# How to use a NN to continuously add a value to a tensor?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to teach my model to add/subtract a value to/from a tensor until that `tensor = 10`.

My model is:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
```

The inputs to the network are:

```
features = torch.rand((10,2)) #10 inputs, each of 2D
```

My goal:

```
x_goal = torch.tensor(10)
```

Training:

```
for epoch in range(1000):
    x = torch.tensor(0.0, requires_grad=True)

    for feature in features:
        x += net(feature)
        loss = torch.square(x_goal - x)
        loss.backward()
```

The main issue that I'm struggling with is the in place operation error:

```
RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

Comment: Just use two operations: `out = net(feature)`. `x = x + out`. Also, `torch.square` should be `torch.pow(x_goal - x,2)` and this is a strange way to train this network because you need to maintain the computation graph for each forward pass

Comment: Neat. The 2 operations solved that error. Any suggestions on changing the way I train? I suppose you mean to do it in batches? ie not `for feature in features`

Comment: Well yes, you should do it in batches. But right now, your loss is based on `x`, which is based on the output of the net and the previous value of `x`, which is itself based on the output of the net. So for a single backwards pass you're trying to backpropogate through the network several times. THis is likely to result in vanishing gradients. So at a minimum you should call `x = x.detach() + out` to prevent this recursive backpropagation

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!